# insert formatted text in ole object

Tags: ms-access

I have a report in which there is a sentence which a certain field needs to be stressed on, that is - it needs to be formatted. Example:

> " Some normal constant text followed be ***important data field*** .
>   Same text field, more text and a second ***important data field***
>   followed by some more text. "

The length of the first "important data field" varies greatly, otherwise I would try and make several text fields with different formatting. Changing the appearance of the text is a no-no.

As Access doesn't allow for different formatting for different parts of the same field I think my only choice is to create an OLE object and programatically add and format the text in it. How to do that?

Maybe I should make a template word document with some macros and somehow pass arguments to those macros to add the different pieces of text with different formatting.

Comment: Which version of Access? Since 2007, you can have rich text: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/insert-or-add-a-rich-text-field-HA010014097.aspx

Comment: Sadly, I need it to be compatible with 2003

Comment: In that case, depending on your report, it may well be best to use Word and merge or bookmarks to publish. An alternative is HTML, which is not too difficult to output. Either of these options, I reckon, would be a lot easier than trying to create and maintain OLE Objects.

Comment: could you point me to some resources about HTML output or "bookmarks"? I think Word merge isn't much better than OLE objects. Just to be clear, I don't want to keep the OLE objects, just to programatically create one when opening a report and delete it after the report is closed.

Comment: @Fionnuala , althout more then 2 years have passed, I guess you should put your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Access 2007, you can use [rich textboxes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-or-add-a-rich-text-field-9f86237d-dbbc-4a85-b12c-9d8dca824630?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), prior to that, depending on your report, it may well be best to use Word and merge or bookmarks to publish. An alternative is HTML, which is not too difficult to output. Either of these options, I reckon, would be a lot easier than trying to create and maintain OLE Objects.